# Dynamic Element Command Binding/INotifyPropertyChanged - TKCustomMap

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, event-handling, inotifypropertychanged

I am using TK.CustomMap and I am having issues executing a method I need to execute in the View. I'm wondering what could be the cause of this. At first I was just using the MapClicked method in the code but now I'm trying to use the Bindable Command Property and I can't tell if it's firing or not. [EDIT] I cannot bind this command in XAML because the elements are all added dynamically in the code behind. I do belive the commands are actually firing and maybe the issue is more with `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation but I'm not sure[EDIT]

Here is the `xaml.cs` binding and MapClicked command

```
  mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.MapClickedCommandProperty, "MapClickedCommand");

    private void MapView_MapClicked(object sender, TKGenericEventArgs<TK.CustomMap.Position> e)
    {
        var map = sender as TKCustomMap;
        if (map.MapClickedCommand != null)
        {
            map.MapClickedCommand.Execute(e);
        }
    }
```

and in the ViewModel the `MapClickedCommand` as well as it's supporting methods and objects

```
public  Command<Position> MapClickedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command<Position>(async (position) =>
        {
            if (!ZoneOpen)
                return;
            ActiveZonePositions.Add(position);

            if (ActiveZonePositions.Count > 1)
            {
                ZonePolyLine.LineCoordinates = ActiveZonePositions;
            }

            var pin = new TKCustomMapPin
            {
                Position = new TK.CustomMap.Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude),
                IsVisible = true,
                IsDraggable = true,
                ShowCallout = false,
            };
            _pins.Add(pin);
            await CreatePointAsync(position);
            PointCount++;
        });
    }
}

public async Task CreatePointAsync(TK.CustomMap.Position position)
{
    var zone = await RetrieveZoneAsync(ActiveZoneID);
    Model.Point PointToAdd = new Model.Point
    {
        ZoneSys = zone.ZoneSys,
        PointName = "",
        Latitude = position.Latitude,
        Longitude = position.Longitude,
        PointOrder = PointCount + 1
    };
    ActiveZonePoints.Add(PointToAdd);
}

public static List<Position> ActiveZonePositions = new List<Position>();
public static List<Model.Point> ActiveZonePoints = new List<Model.Point>();
    public static int ActiveZoneID;
    public static int ActivePointID;
    public static int PointCount;
    public static bool ZoneOpen = false;

public ObservableCollection<TKCustomMapPin> Pins
{
    get { return _pins; }
    set
    {
        if (_pins != value)
        {
            _pins = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Pins");
        }
    }
}
```

There is an OpenNewZone() method that set `ZoneOpen` to true.

and here are the various property changed listeners etc. for the `_pins` list

```
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

ObservableCollection<TKCustomMapPin> _pins;
```

and the ViewModel's method

```
public MapPageViewModel()
        {
            _pins = new ObservableCollection<TKCustomMapPin>();
        }
```

So I'm thinking that with the property changed listener it should add a pin to the map as soon as I click on it but it doesn't. It's probably that I'm missing something about Bindings but I feel like I have read through all the articles and lots of questions and have covered all the bases.

Anyone see what I'm missing?

addendum:
I also know that the map is sensing clicks because I see this in the Output in VS

```
07-08 18:42:48.711 D/ViewRootImpl@af05362[MainActivity](30715): ViewPostIme pointer 0
07-08 18:42:48.787 D/ViewRootImpl@af05362[MainActivity](30715): ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out. Needed to change a method I was using as a command. The `OpenNewZone` method I mentioned was bound as a command. It turns out that commands can be bound this way without issue. The only problem was that the `OpenNewZone` Command wasn't setting the `ZoneOpen` bool to true because it wasn't firing. I had it set as a method but setting it this way

```
public Command<EventArgs> OpenNewZone
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<EventArgs>(async e =>
            {
                ZoneOpen = true;
                PointCount = 0;
                ActiveZonePositions.Clear();
                Zone ZoneToAdd = new Zone
                {
                    Contactsys = MobileUser.ContactSys,
                    ZoneTypesSys = 1,
                    OrganizationSys = MobileUser.OrganizationSys,
                    ZoneName = ""
                };

                ActiveZoneID = await AddZoneToDBAsync(ZoneToAdd);
                ZoneToAdd.ID = ActiveZoneID;
                ZoneToAdd.ZoneSys = ActiveZoneID;
                await AddZoneToDBAsync(ZoneToAdd);
            });
        }
    }
```

and then the binding this way

```
Binding openNewZone = new Binding("OpenNewZone");
addZoneButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, openNewZone);
addZoneButton.Clicked += AddZoneButton_Clicked;
```

Then the Clicked Event handler like this

```
 private void AddZoneButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        MapField.Children.Remove(button);

        if (button.Command != null)
        {
            button.Command.Execute(e);
        }

        zoneControls.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        zoneControls.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
        zoneControls.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        zoneControls.HeightRequest = 35;

        MapField.Children.Add(zoneControls);
        zoneControls.Children.Add(saveZoneButton);
        zoneControls.Children.Add(setZonePropsButton);
        zoneControls.Children.Add(deleteZoneButton);
        zoneControls.Children.Add(closeControlsButton);
    }
```

Works flawlessly every time. So everything in my original question was actually correct!! DOH!!

But this is great because now I know how to write and bind commands perfectly on dynamically added elements while still maintaining MVVM structure.

The TK.CustomMap nuget has its own Binding Properties so they are set a little different but everything is working perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right way to set command bindings. Command bindings generally are used in xaml. An object exposes an property of type ICommand, then in xaml you bind the Command property to that ICommand.

The object would declare the command like this:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public ICommand MyCommand {get;set;}

    public MyViewModel()
    {
       MyCommand = new Command(Command_MyCommand);
    }

    public void Command_MyCommand(object paramter)
    {
       // do something nifty
    }
}
```

In the code behind, set the `BindingContext` to an instance of `MyViewModel`.

Then in xaml, you can bind the command property to the command:

```
<Button Text="Press me!" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

To set the command programmatically, you just assign in:

```
SomeControl.Command = MyViewModelInstance.MyCommand;
```

If you want to do it in code behind, it's easier to just subscribe to the event.

** Update: With your control, it would look something like this:

```
   mapView.CommandClickedCommand = new Command(Map_ClickedCommand);

   public async void Map_ClickedCommand(object p1)
   {
        var position = p1 as Position; // not sure what the type of position is

        if (!ZoneOpen)
            return;
        ActiveZonePositions.Add(position);

        if (ActiveZonePositions.Count > 1)
        {
            ZonePolyLine.LineCoordinates = ActiveZonePositions;
        }

        var pin = new TKCustomMapPin
        {
            Position = new TK.CustomMap.Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude),
            IsVisible = true,
            IsDraggable = true,
            ShowCallout = false,
        };
        _pins.Add(pin);
        await CreatePointAsync(position);
        PointCount++;
    };
```

Comment: I can't use bindings in xaml because the map, buttons etc. are being added dynamically in the code behind. How would you bind an element added dynamically to a command? It seems like it's firing the command because I had some issues where it was throwing null references earlier and I fixed those and I'm not getting those errors anymore. Is it possible the problem is more due to improper implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged event?

Comment: I added an example of it. You just set the Control's command property to the command. On with your code `mapView.MapClicked = new Command(CommandMethod);` where `CommandMethod` is just a method that takes a single object parameter.

Comment: I was just able to verify that the longpress command I set up in the same way is working. So It's not the way I set up the binding. It's something else. Thanks for your help though. You got me to dig a little deeper at least.